# MDX and AVG function

Tags: mdx, average

Not sure if this is the right place for MDX question but it seemed to be the most appropriate.

I have a question about MDX and the AVG function.

I would like to compute the average sale amount by day across several month for a year.

So I would like to compute the AVG of the 2010/01/01, 2010/02/01, 2010/03/01, etc... and this for everyday of the month.

Can anyone give me a hint on how I'd be able to do that ?

I would go for something that looks like this

`WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Total] AS AVG(DESCENDANTS([Time].[2010], [Day]),[Measure].[Sale])`

Thank you,

**UPDATE**

I have open a new question with a clearer explanation of my problem and study case.

Please find it at : [MDX: avg advanced use](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175962/mdx-avg-advanced-use)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are on the right track. You can compute the average with:

```
WITH
MEMBER [Measures].[Average Sales] AS
    AVG(DESCENDANTS([Time].[Calendar].CurrentMember, 
                    [Time].[Calendar].[Date]), 
        [Measure].[Sale])
SELECT
{
    [Measures].[Average Sales]
} ON 0,
{
    [Time].[Calendar].[Month]
} ON 1
FROM [YourCube]
```

This will give you the average for each member of the Calendar hierarchy of the Time dimension which you select. It will work for Years, Quarters, Months, etc and will average the Sale measure over days under the specified members. In your case you can just select Month on ROWS or COLUMNS as shown in the code sample.

Comment: Thank you Boyan for this answer. But my problem is to get the average by day and grouped by day accros the different month. From waht I get your answer will return me the global average by [Year|Quart|Month|Day]. Please correct me if Im wrong.

Comment: It will give you average({day1,day2,day3...day31},sales) for each month

Comment: @Spredzy, don't get it, if we take the 3 January what exactly to you want to calculate? (1 Jan) + (2 Jan) + (3 Jan) / 3 ? what about feb.

Comment: @icCube what I want is for a given year let's say 2010, I want to have the average sale by day in the month. So what the average sale for every 1 of the month and 2, 3, 4 ... 30, 31
@BoyanPenev I'll try it and let you know. Thank you for those answers.

Comment: The above MDX will give you average over dates for _any_ member of any level of the hierarchy. For 2010 you'll get the avg over all its dates, etc. You can of course change this if you want to get the avg of children instead - let me know after you try it.

Comment: @Boyan, I've tried what you wrote but it does not provide what I want. I opened a new question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6175962/mdx-avg-advanced-use If you can please take a quick look it. Thank you.